# Playing radio via the speaker

Tags: lumia, 7.5

Is it possible to play the radio through the speaker and not through the earphones? I've looked at the settings while the radio is playing, and the only option seems to be to save the current channel as a favourite.

*edit* The phone is a Lumia 610.

Comment: This is possible in Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FM Radio in Lumia 610 does not support loudspeaker ([source](http://www.nokia.com/in-en/support/troubleshooting/?action=singleFAQ&caseid=FA139157_en_US)).

For other devices, select and hold the station number, and select switch to speaker or switch to headset.

You still need to keep the headphones plugged in as the cord acts as the radio antenna.

Comment: I am aware that the earphones need to remain in, but even on old feature phones this function is easy to find.

Comment: Yeah it is a bit strange that the speaker option is hidden under the station frequency.

Comment: I tried it, selecting and holding on the station number, and just the normal menu pops up ("pin to start" and "settings"). I guess the 610 doesn't have that option then.

Comment: You are right it doesn't "The FM Radio in Lumia 610 does not support loudspeaker." http://www.nokia.com/in-en/support/troubleshooting/?action=singleFAQ&caseid=FA139157_en_US

Comment: Absolutely bizarre that the 610 would not have this feature. Thank you for the info

Comment: I tried to hold station number and didn't get any options :-(

Comment: @Prawin What's your device?